# iOS UITableView the headerView was not hidden

Tags: ios, uitableview, refresh

I have a question about the usage of `EGORefreshTableHeaderView`:

**If I use this code, it is okay:**

```
 - (void)egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView *)view  
{
    _reloading = YES; 
    [self performSelector:@selector(refreshData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
}

 - (void)refreshData
{
    _reloading = NO;
   [self.dataSourceArr removeAllObjects]; 
   [self.dataSourceArr addNewData];
   [self.egoHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDataSourceDidFinishedLoading:self.mainTableView];
   [self.mainTableView reloadData];
}
```

However, when I use this code,the `EGOrefreshHeaderView` will show at `mainTableView` top all along, it doesn't hide:

```
 - (void)egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView *)view  
{
    _reloading = YES; 
    [self refreshData];
}
 - (void)refreshData
{
    _reloading = NO;
   [self.dataSourceArr removeAllObjects]; 
   [self.dataSourceArr addNewData];
   [self.egoHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDataSourceDidFinishedLoading:self.mainTableView];
   [self.mainTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Can you please format your code ? Nothing is readable .

Comment: i'm sorry,and it's ok now

Comment: Either check `self.egoHeaderView` or `self.mainTableView` if it is nil. And if they are `IBOutlet`, then check they are connected properly to the xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top bit of code runs like this:

```
// someone calls egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh
    [_delegate egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:self]
        // sets up a refreshData to run after set period of time
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(60.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // a
// some time later, refreshData runs
    [self.egoHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDataSourceDidFinishedLoading:self.mainTableView];
        [scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];  // b
```

The bottom bit runs like this:

```
// someone calls egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh
    [_delegate egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:self]
        [self refreshData];
            [self.egoHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDataSourceDidFinishedLoading:self.mainTableView];
                [scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];  // b
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(60.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // a
```

lines `a` and `b` are reversed. Even though the changes are animated, the second line overrides the first.

**Fix 1:**

Modify the file `EGORefreshTableHeaderView.h`

Change `- (void)egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:...` to `- (bool)egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:...`

Modify the file `EGORefreshTableHeaderView.m`

Change `- (void)egoRefreshScrollViewDidEndDragging:`

```
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:)]) {
    if([_delegate egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:self]) {
       return;
    }
}
```

And finally change your `egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:`

```
- (bool)egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView *)view  
{
    _reloading = YES; 
    [self refreshData];
    return true;
}
```

**Fix 2:**

If you don't want to change the third party code, the top version is the only way. You can specify 0 for the duration and that should queue the selector to run after.